# issues with javascript url redirect for blogger

Tags: javascript, url, redirect

This code is a redirector for the blogger, but is not redirecting to the link after "url =", is redirecting to the link in "else"

```
function linkProtetor(link) {
   var lnk = link;
   lnk = lnk.substr(lnk.search("url=") + 4);
   return lnk;
 }

 var linkpro = window.parent.document.location.href;
 linkpro = linkProtetor(linkpro);

 var ss = -1;

 function atualizaContador(futuro) {
   ss = (ss == -1) ? futuro : ss;
   var faltam = 'Você será redirecionado para a pagina em ' + ss + ' segundos.';

   if (ss > 0) {
     document.getElementById('contador').innerHTML = faltam;
     ss--;
     setTimeout(atualizaContador, 1000);
   } else {
     document.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
   }
 }
```

Comment: Where and how are you calling `atualizaContador `

Comment: I need it redirected to the link at the end of the url=
example: "link.com/redirect?url=gmail.com"

Comment: look at the entire code: [https://pastebin.com/KKDEZPvm](https://pastebin.com/KKDEZPvm)

Comment: @Sushanth-- can you help me?